# login without password from one docker container into another

Tags: docker, authentication, jenkins, openssh

I have created 2 docker containers. One Jenkins and one container running an openssh server with ubuntu base.
I configured Jenkins container buy pulling Jenkins image and for openssh server I have created the image using Dockerfile.
I generated key files and copied the public key to authorized_keys of the openssh server.
and then when i try to login via Jenkins container into openssh server using
ssh -i remote-key remote_user@remote-host it is prompting me to give password.

Here is my DockerFile and docker-compose
DockerFile:

```
From ubuntu
Run apt-get update
Run apt-get install -y openssh-server
Run useradd -m -d /home/remote_user remote_user && \
    echo "remote_user:1234" |chpasswd  && \
    mkdir -p /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh
Copy remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorised_keys
Run chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorised_keys
RUN service ssh start
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]`
```

docker-compose

```
    version: '3'
services:
        jenkins:
                container_name: jenkins
                image: jenkins/jenkins
                ports:
                     -   "8080:8080"
                volumes:
                     -  "/home/sarthak/jenkins/jenkins1/jenkins1_home:/var/jenkins_home"
                networks:
                     -   net
        remote_host:
                container_name: remote-host
                image: remote-host
                build:
                        context: /home/sarthak/jenkins/jenkins1/
                networks:
                     -   net
networks:
        net:
```

login via password is successful but i need a password less login. Please help

Comment: Try changing `authorised_keys` to `authorized_keys`.

Comment: @MarkoE : Thank you for pointing it out. Silly mistakes leads to big difference. It worked

Comment: I'll post it as an answer also, so you can mark it as correct.

Comment: Btw: maybe you want to check out the [Docker Buildkit feature for managing credentials](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds)? Helped me a lot with the SSH-mess in my jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `authorised_keys` to `authorized_keys` when creating `Dockerfile`, two lines have the same issue:

```
COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and

```
RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```